# bash cgi program output

Tags: bash, shell, cgi, output

I have a program that spits out pure bytes of a PNG image. I've been trying to attach this output with a bash cgi script that spits out a simple html web page with the output of the program attached as the data.

I.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
parm=($QUERY_STRING) # capture the query string (from url)
output=$(java -jar Program.jar $parm) # capture the bytes of the PNG image
len=${#output} # figure out the size of the png image

# simple web page with png image
resp="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: $len\r\n\r\n$output"

echo -en $resp # cgi teleport that hogwash out
```

This works fine if I pipe the request through TCP to an intermediate server program but that has the disadvantage that I have to have a separate server program running to link the cgi scripts to the programs.

Thank you for help!

[EDIT]

Ahh, I've figured it out. It was as simple as the following:

```
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok"
...
java -jar program.jar @parm
```

Comment: StackOverFlow allows you to answer your own question.  This is a good  idea, since it could help someone in the future.  Suggest you move the answer from your earlier edit into the answer box.

Comment: I tried that the first time round but there was was a 10 hour delay before you could answer your own post. I've fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I've figured it out. It was as simple as the following:

```
echo "HTTP/1.1 200 Ok"
...
java -jar program.jar @parm
```

(the program outputs the data (bytes of the image) into std out. When I wrapped inside bash's "echo" it seems it wrapped the bytes into a string.